# Kivy does not provide a python shell on yosemite

Tags: osx-yosemite, kivy

I failed to let kivy work on my mac (yosemite 10.10.4). After placing kivy in applications and running makesymlinks, I expected to get a python shell after the 'kivy' command. However, I got the following error.

```
Script started, output file is started
Script: on: No such file or directory

Script done, output file is started
/usr/local/bin/kivy: line 2: bash-3.2$: command not found
/usr/local/bin/kivy: line 3: bash:: command not found
/usr/local/bin/kivy: line 4: bash-3.2$: command not found 
: command not found: line 5: Password:
/usr/local/bin/kivy: line 6: sudo:: command not found
/usr/local/bin/kivy: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
'usr/local/bin/kivy: line 7: `bash-3.2$ exit()
```

Meanwhile I started developing on ubuntu, which works fine, but if I want to deploy my app on my ipad, it seems that I still need kivy nicely installed on my mac, because buildozer seems to require to run on mac when deploying for iOS.

Any tips are very welcome.

Note: I tried macport too, but received the following error
    Error: org.macports.build for port py27-kivy returned: command        execution failed
    Please see the log file for port py27-kivy for details:
            /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports    .org_release_tarballs_ports_python_py-kivy/py27-kivy/main.log
    To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
        http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
    Error: Processing of port py27-kivy failed

Comment: You may have more luck asking on the kivy mailing list for a question like this.

Comment: I am on the same os, running kivy from command line just works, what exactly could be different on your system? Could you run the commands from the script one by one to see which one fails first?

Comment: Good idea, does anybody know which script is actually called? On which path can I find the script which is called with the 'kivy' command. 
Nice to hear that you had succes on Yosemite, gives me hope...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up to conclude that the Kivy installation was corrupt. Re-installing it was not enough, but first uninstalling the existing one, and afterwards install a fresh download brought a solution.
I found this solution thanks to qua-non, who was also active in the kivy users support group. Thanks!